# Environment independent maven builds

Tags: java, maven, environment

We are implementing a CI (git + maven + jenkins) in our organisation and one of the solution I came across is to have multiple maven profiles for each environment. But we are looking at a technique of building the artifact once and then be able to use it in every environment.

**Our Approach:**

- Project.war

  - WEB-INF
  - META-INF
  - env

    - dev

      - lib   (contains dev jars)
      - resources (contains dev properties)
    - uat

      - lib
      - resources
    - prod

And in jenkins build task, we have a task before deployment which execute shell/bat commands to replace environment specific env/${env}/libs/*.jars and env/${env}/resources/*.properties files in war

**Commands**

```
cd target
jar xvf demo-war.war
del /Q /S ".\WEB-INF\lib"
xcopy ".\env\dev\lib" ".\WEB-INF\lib" /y
xcopy ".\env\dev\resources" ".\classes\resources\" /y
jar uvf demo-war.war ".\classes\resources"
jar uvf demo-war.war ".\WEB-INF\lib"
```

This modified war will then be deployed to environment specific containers.

---

So my question to experts is, will this be the correct approach to go forward?

Comment: First why do you need different jars for different environments? Furthermore property files can be handled by this https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin

Comment: well, that's the problem. these jars are third party vendor jars and they provide us jars for different environment

update: The multienv-maven-plugin also creates one artifact for each environment.  Should this be a standard industry approach and ok to use "Per environment artifacts?"

Comment: If those jars are 3rd party jars they belong into a separate build or should be uploaded to a repository manager...

Comment: I uploaded the jars to nexus repository but then how do I configure my single WAR artifact to deploy on different environment.

Comment: You didn't answer my question: Why do you need different jar's for different environments?

Comment: We have SOAP calls to third party vendors and they provide us with WSDLs for each environment. Our team generates client jars and use it in applications.

Comment: Why are WSDL's environment dependent? I think this is the issue..

Comment: We have a lot of legacy code and the jars were created from wsdl using apache axis and changing this is not an option.

Comment: If your code gets built without referring to any specific variation of vendor JARs, you can just modify deployment process to deploy environment specific vendor JARs to the servers.
If the vendor JARs are needed for build, you can modify POM to indicate the dependencies as "provided". That way Maven won't look for those JARs during build lifecycle, but the server will expect them to be present in CLASSPATH.